# Merging records of custom data type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have some data type

```
data SomeType = SomeType { a :: Maybe Int
                         , b :: Maybe String
                         , c :: Maybe OtherType }
```

and two variables of the type

```
st1 = SomeType (Just 1) (Just "hello") Nothing
st2 = SomeType Nothing (Just "world") Nothing
```

How would I merge them prioritising the second one?

```
merged = SomeType (Just 1) (Just "world") Nothing
```

Here `a st2` is `Nothing`, so `Just 1` from `a st1` is preferred.
For `b`, `Just "world"` from `st2` overrides `st1`'s `Just "hello"`.

My simple approach would be to do something like

```
merge :: SomeType -> SomeType -> SomeType
merge (SomeType a1 b1 c1) (SomeType a2 b2 c2) = 
  SomeType { a = maybe a1 pure a2 
           , b = maybe b1 pure b2
           , c = maybe c1 pure c2 }
```

The actual type is larger than this example and `c :: Maybe OtherType` needs to be merged recursively as well.

**Edit**:
Also, I'm aware of record field update in the following form

```
st1 { b = Just "world" }
```

to create new record with updated fields. 
Not sure if this helps in my case.

Comment: What is the problem of your approach in question? it seems workable.

Comment: The simple approach I have there seems a bit too tedious and I wasn't sure how to handle nested custom types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function with the type `SomeType -> SomeType -> SomeType` looks like a candidate for a `Semigroup`, or at least something that can be implemented with `Semigroup`. There's a couple of options.

## Explicit merge

If you keep `SomeType` as in the OP, you could write an explicit `merge` function like this:

```
merge :: SomeType -> SomeType -> SomeType
merge x y = toSomeType $ toTriple x <> toTriple y
  where
    toTriple (SomeType a b c) = (Last <$> a, Last <$> b, c)
    toSomeType (a, b, c) = SomeType (getLast <$> a) (getLast <$> b) c
```

This converts each `SomeType` instance to a triple (three-tuple), for which a `Semigroup` instance exists if all three elements have `Semigroup` instances.

There's more than one `Semigroup` instance for `Maybe`, but (from GHC 8.4) any `Maybe a` is a `Semigroup` (and `Monoid`) instance when `a` is a `Semigroup` instance.

The `Semigroup` instance that favours the last of two values is `Last`, so `toTriple` maps `a` and `b` to `Maybe Last` values. It doesn't, however, map `c`, because in this implementation it assumes that `OtherType` is already a `Semigroup` instance (see below).

Since the resulting triples are themselves `Semigroup` instances, they can be combined with the `<>` operator. This gives you a resulting triple that you can convert back to a `SomeType` value with `toSomeType`.

## Semigroup instances

You could also simply make the types themselves `Semigroup` instances. I think this is best if there's no ambiguity. In itself, `Maybe` can be more than one `Semigroup` instance, e.g. favouring the `First` or `Last` value, respectively.

If you *always* want to favour the `Last` value, however, you can make this explicit in the type. Here's one way `OtherType` could look:

```
data OtherType =
  OtherType { foo :: Maybe (Last Int), bar :: Maybe (Last String) } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Notice that the fields aren't just `Maybe` values, but explicitly `Maybe Last` values. This gives rise to an unambiguous `Semigroup` instance:

```
instance Semigroup OtherType where
  (OtherType foo1 bar1) <> (OtherType foo2 bar2) =
    OtherType (foo1 <> foo2) (bar1 <> bar2)
```

You could also follow the same design principle for `SomeType`, which would make the explicit `merge` function redundant.

## Examples

You can try out the above functionality in GHCi:

```
*Q54068475> merge st1 st2
SomeType {a = Just 1, b = Just "world", c = Nothing}
*Q54068475> ot1 = OtherType (Just (Last 42)) (Just (Last "foo"))
*Q54068475> ot2 = OtherType (Just (Last 1337)) Nothing
*Q54068475> merge (SomeType (Just 1) (Just "hello") (Just ot1))
                  (SomeType Nothing (Just "world") (Just ot2))
SomeType {a = Just 1,
          b = Just "world",
          c = Just (OtherType {foo = Just (Last {getLast = 1337}),
                               bar = Just (Last {getLast = "foo"})})}
```

(I've added a few line breaks to the GHCi session to make it more readable...)

## Monoids

These types could also be `Monoid` instances:

```
instance Monoid OtherType where
  mempty = OtherType Nothing Nothing
```

This could come in useful, so you might as well consider adding those instances as well...

Comment: Isn't `Maybe (Last ...)` a bit redundant? Why not just `Last ...`?

Comment: @Carl The `Last` type used above is the one from `Data.Semigroup`, not the one from `Data.Monoid`. While [the documentation for that type](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Last) states that you can *Use Option (Last a) to get the behavior of Last from Data.Monoid*, the `Option` wrapper will be deprecated because `Semigroup` is now a superclas of `Monoid`. So `Maybe (Last a)` seems to be the enduring abstraction...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works great and introduces me to more Haskell concepts.
One more thing though, if I have a large data type with many attributes, defining the `<>` gets pretty long. Is there any shorthand for it?

Comment: @n.z. If you define the types so that they have unambiguous `Semigroup` instances, you may be able to use a GHC extension like `DeriveAnyClass`, but I'm not sure. It's also possible you can make something work with the `Generic` type class, or with Template Haskell, but none of those are my area of expertise, so I may be wrong about those suggestions...

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the `Alternative` instance for `Maybe` types.

```
import Control.Applicative  -- for <|>
merge (SomeType a1 b1 c1) (SomeType a2 b2 c2)
    = SomeType (a2 <|> a1) (b2 <|> b1) (c2 <|> c1)
```

For `Maybe` types, `(<|>)` returns its first argument if it is not `Nothing`, otherwise it returns its second arguments. To prioritize the *second* argument of `merge`, use its component as the first argument for `<|>` in each case.

In order to handle both `SomeType` and `OtherType`, you might want to use a type class.

```
class Mergeable a where
    merge a1 a2 :: a -> a -> a

instance Mergeable SomeType where
    merge (SomeType a1 b1 c1) (SomeType a2 b2 c2)
    = SomeType (a2 <|> a1) (b2 <|> b1) (merge <$> c1 <*> c2)  -- not merge c2 c1

instance Mergeable OtherType where
    merge (OtherType a1 b1) (OtherType a2 b2) = ...
```

Comment: c1 and c2 are `Maybe OtherType` so `merge c1 c2` would not work.
Need something like `instance (Mergeable a) => Mergeable (Maybe a) where; merge a Nothing = a; merge Nothing b = b; merge a b = merge <$> a <*> b`  
 
**Edit**: formatting for no code block in comment

Comment: Oops. `merge <$> c1 <*> c2` would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

For simple case you can use `orElse`.

If you need to merge data if it presents in both objects you can create helper

```
mergeHelper :: (a -> a-> a) -> Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
mergeHelper _ None x = x
mergeHelper _ (Maybe x) _ = Maybe x
mergeHelper f (Maybe x) (Maybe y) = Maybe $ f x y
```